# VueJS Authentication with Django REST Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, axios

I can retrieve a key after logging in through my Django REST API, but then I am wondering how I should store that key. I'm not really using Django, but I imagine I have to store the cookie myself then or something. I'm using Axios for VueJS to interact with the API. I am using [django rest auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) to get the token.

Comment: related: [how to save a users session VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798033/how-to-save-a-users-session-vuejs),

Answer (score 0):

Keep it easy to Local Storage or SessionStorage after get token from Backend-Response and then pass it in every Request in Axios Header-config.

DRF auth Token get it from header with this format:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Add this section code to your Axios configs to get token from LocalStorage.

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use(
 (config) => {
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
   if (token) {
     config.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
   }
   return config;
 },
 (error) => {
   return Promise.reject(error);
 }
);
```