# How to store sessions in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, session

Is it possible to store data in sessions in Vue js and use them later in your application? Right now I'm displaying all of the `candidate_profiles` on a page and I want to store the name `{{candidateProfile.name}}` in a session variable so that I can send this data to the server side via a form of course (there are other fields on the page but just to simplify I'm showing only the name here).

```
<div v-for="(candidateProfile, index) in candidateProfiles" :key="index">
   {{candidateProfile.name}}

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" v-on:click="showInterviewModal()">Request an Interview</button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798033/how-to-save-users-sessions-with-vuejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save users sessions with VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798033/how-to-save-users-sessions-with-vuejs)

Comment: I’m not looking to store the user’s data in a session when he logs in, I’m looking to store data based on action within the application. For example if you look at Laravel Sessions in the docs, you can see how easy it is to create session variables from your controllers to your .blade files. But now I’m building an SPA and using Vue components. I’m looking for a clear example.

Comment: by "later" you mean you want persistent access to specific data even if the user navigates to a different site?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant save them while a single user is using the application. I ended up finding  another solution and I see now they made use of a npm package called "vue-session". So I can always google how to do that if I need to later.